# Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `closable`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd, styled-components

I have this code

```
import { Modal } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";

export const StANTModal = styled(Modal)`
  & .ant-modal-content {
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
`;
```

and using like this

```
 <StANTModal
      visible={showModal}
      footer={false}
      closable={false}
      onCancel={() => setShowModal(false)}
      transitionName="ant-move-down"
      maskTransitionName="ant-move-down"
      width={600}
    >
    // not related code
  </StANTModal>
```

and I have this log

```
warning :react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `visible`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: visible="false" or visible={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with visible={condition && value}, pass visible={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
```

It works perfectly but I don't want to see this log in my console.

I am using react with Typescript and ant design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is from antd library